# How to update attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whenever, feedzirra

I have problem with update attributs. I try to update via cron.

sheduler.rb

```
every 3.minutes do
  runner "update_from_feed_continuously(feed_url)"
end
```

feed_entry.rb

```
class FeedEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :guid, :name, :url, :feed_url
  after_create { |feed| FeedEntry.update_from_feed(feed.feed_url) }
  def self.update_from_feed(feed_url)
    feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(feed_url)
    add_entries(feed.entries)
  end

  def self.update_from_feed_continuously(feed_url)
    feed = Feedzirra::Feed.update(feed)
    add_entries(feed.new_entries) if feed.updated?
  end

  private
  def self.add_entries(entries)
    entries.each do |entry|
      unless exists? :guid => entry.id
        create!(
          :name => entry.title, 
          :url => entry.url, 
          :guid => entry.id
        )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I use gem feedzirra and gem whenever

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.13)
1.9.3p392 :001 > FeedEntry.update_from_feed_continuously(feed_url)
NameError: undefined local variable or method `feed_url' for main:Object
from (irb):1
from /Users/ipatov/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/ipatov/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/ipatov/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

1.9.3p392 :002 >

I am trying to ipmplement railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/168-feed-parsing. initially I tried to load the feed_url through console and then update via cron

Comment: What is your problem? Show the error message

Comment: Where is `feed_url` defined for scheduler.rb?  Is that supposed to be derived from a route?

Comment: Wouldn't you need to actually pass in a feed URL? Which also means your method is wrong, because you pass in a feed url but try to operate on a feed without looking up the feed (by URL?)

Comment: feed url set via FeedEntry.update_from_feed("http://example.com/rss")

Comment: @Anton: I mean in scheduler.rb you are calling `update_from_feed_continuously(feed_url)`, but `feed_url` hasn't been defined yet.  What url are you trying to pass in?

Comment: I am trying to ipmplement railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/168-feed-parsing. initially I tried to load the feed_url through console and then update via cron